# Exporting web table to Excel

Tags: excel, web

http://rase.paragonrels.com/publink/default.aspx?GUID=456daf07-e0d3-43ae-a894-2c10e7acd9c5&Report=Yes

I am trying to export this table into Excel and it is pasting into one column. When looking at the source code it does not look like a standard HTML table.

Is there a simple way to export this data into Excel so that columns and field names are intact?

Comment: Wow, what a delicious kind of DIV soup seasoned with inline styles. No chance to get this into table data, I believe. Maybe this exactly is the reason for this HTML presentation, protecting the data from being foreign used?

Answer (score 0):

Define simple?  At a glance, this is the simplest method I can think of:

1) Highlight the data & paste it into Excel.  I tested this & it outputs the data into one column.

2) Write a macro to parse the into table format.

As far as macros go, it shouldn't be too hard.  How good are you with VBA?